# mac OSX Yosemite, safe mode?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, safe-mode

how do i launch safe mode on mac, with boot camp installed(windows 7)?
Without boot camp u just press shift on the sound, but with bootcamp installed it always login in windows? help!!macbook air.

Comment: Did you set your Startup Disk to the Mac HD? To check, go to System Preferences > Startup Disk. Select "Macintosh HD". Click "Restart..." and hold `shift` when you hear the startup chime. Safe mode?

Comment: thanks @Arc676 i switch it and it worked good man! helped a lot.

Comment: @Arc676 can have ur twitter?

Comment: I don't use Twitter, although you can search for users in the StackExchange chatrooms (I'm usually in NSChat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick search I found this information:

> If you're in Windows, you can switch to the Mac OS X partition using the Boot Camp icon in the System Tray. Click the gray diamond-shaped icon, and click "Restart in Mac OS" from the pop-up menu. Then, confirm your choice to reboot to Mac OS X.

When you back in OS X you can change the startup disk via sys. pref. > startup disk

Comment: thanks i switch the startup disk and it worked i'm in safe mode now and i did what i wanted t thanks.

Comment: Also you can change which disk to boot from by pressing and holding the `Option` key after the startup chime then using the arrow keys and `return` key to select disk